# Table-Per-Type and many inherit one base class

Tags: entity-framework

I have two class and want use TPT

```
public class Book {
    public int BookId { get;set; }
    public string Title { get;set; }
}

public class BookInLibrary : Book {
    public int CopyNumber { get; set;}
    public bool IsBorrowed { get;set; }
}
```

The problem is that how can I insert two BookInLibrarys with the same book entity?

Like this:

> **Book (BookId, Title)**
>
> Book (1, Harry Potter - The Philosopher's Stone);
>
> **BookInLibrary(BookId, CopyNumber, IsBorrowed)**
>
> BookInLibrary(1, 1, false)
>
> BookInLibrary(1, 2, false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an association not an inheritance and your class model should be like this:

```
public class Book {
    public int BookId { get;set; }
    public string Title { get;set; }
}

public class BookInLibrary{
    public int Bookid {get;set;}
    public Book Book {get;set;}
    public int CopyNumber { get; set;}
    public bool IsBorrowed { get;set; }
}
```

Preferably if you renamed the `BookinLibrary` to `BookInstance` or `BookCopy`. Something to be more meaningful

And in case you will not maintain a one to one relationship for each borrowed book, you can simply put a `CopiesAvailable` property inside the `Book` class and increase or decrease it whenever a book is borrowed or returned.